# Unknown cause of recent kernel panics

Tags: mac-pro, kernel-panic

I've recently been having kernel panics to my Mac Pro 3,1 that all seem to occur after my computer has gone to sleep (so mostly overnight). I've been getting them once a day, but have no idea what might be causing it. I can't run the AHT on startup (tried a bunch of methods to put it back on the hard drive, none work). It seems as though the last 6 reports have the same type 14=page fault.

```
Sun Jan 12 02:18:06 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80030dc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800303064b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000038, CR3: 0x0000000005f50000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000051, RDX: 0xffffff7f85305b70
RSP: 0xffffff8311df3e00, RBP: 0xffffff8311df3e40, RSI: 0x00000000299e72b6, RDI: 0xffffff8039b50040
R8:  0xffffff8317e9d078, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff8311df3d80, R11: 0x0000000000000206
R12: 0xffffff8317e9d048, R13: 0xffffff8039b50040, R14: 0xffffff8039b50000, R15: 0xffffff8317e9d000
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff800303064b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000038, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8311df3a90 : 0xffffff8003022f69 
0xffffff8311df3b10 : 0xffffff80030dc19e 
0xffffff8311df3ce0 : 0xffffff80030f3606 
0xffffff8311df3d00 : 0xffffff800303064b 
0xffffff8311df3e40 : 0xffffff800304c070 
0xffffff8311df3f10 : 0xffffff80030cee09 
0xffffff8311df3f50 : 0xffffff80030e21c6 
0xffffff8311df3f80 : 0xffffff80030db75f 
0xffffff8311df3fd0 : 0xffffff80030f37c9 
0xffffff83238fbf50 : 0xffffff800303757a 
0xffffff83238fbf90 : 0xffffff80030378c8 
0xffffff83238fbfb0 : 0xffffff80030d6aa7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003000000
System model name: MacPro3,1 (Mac-F42C88C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 64393224659952
last loaded kext at 62249672613690: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7f8596a000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 51098164804605: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7f8596a000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.filesystems.prlufs    2010.12.28
com.parallels.kext.vnic 9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.hidhook  9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   9.0 24172.951362
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
rabb.it.driver.RabbitEars   2.1.4
com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport 4.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.18
com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver  3.9.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.ATIRadeonX2000    8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   360.8.14
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.kext.AMD4800Controller    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver 1.1.9
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.iPodSBCDriver  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntel8254XEthernet    3.1.3b1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   700.36.24
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.3f17
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.1.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    380
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
Model: MacPro3,1, BootROM MP31.006C.B05, 8 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz, 28 GB, SMC 1.25f4
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4870, ATI Radeon HD 4870, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 1, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 2, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 1, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 2, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 3, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0D9B, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 4, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0D9B, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 3, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000463732353642363145353636374600
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 4, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000463732353642363145353636374600
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 22 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Ethernet 2, Ethernet, en1
PCI Card: NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, Display Controller, Slot-2
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 4870, Display Controller, Slot-1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series, 256.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS723020BLA642, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST3000DM001-9YN166, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST2000DM001-9YN164, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST3000DM001-9YN166, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS722020ALA330, 2 TB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Xbox NUI Camera
USB Device: Xbox NUI Audio
USB Device: Xbox NUI Motor
USB Device: iPod
USB Device: Logitech Camera
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
FireWire Device: unknown_device, Unknown
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Here is another report for comparison if it helps from just 1 day prior:

```
Sat Jan 11 00:22:08 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80082dc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800823064b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000038, CR3: 0x000000000b150000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000051, RDX: 0xffffff7f8a505b70
RSP: 0xffffff8316ebce00, RBP: 0xffffff8316ebce40, RSI: 0x00000000299e72b6, RDI: 0xffffff803ed90040
R8:  0xffffff831cf6d078, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff8316ebcd80, R11: 0x0000000007200b91
R12: 0xffffff831cf6d048, R13: 0xffffff803ed90040, R14: 0xffffff803ed90000, R15: 0xffffff831cf6d000
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff800823064b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000038, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8316ebca90 : 0xffffff8008222f69 
0xffffff8316ebcb10 : 0xffffff80082dc19e 
0xffffff8316ebcce0 : 0xffffff80082f3606 
0xffffff8316ebcd00 : 0xffffff800823064b 
0xffffff8316ebce40 : 0xffffff800824c070 
0xffffff8316ebcf10 : 0xffffff80082cee09 
0xffffff8316ebcf50 : 0xffffff80082e21c6 
0xffffff8316ebcf80 : 0xffffff80082db75f 
0xffffff8316ebcfd0 : 0xffffff80082f37c9 
0xffffff8328c2bf50 : 0xffffff800823757a 
0xffffff8328c2bf90 : 0xffffff80082378c8 
0xffffff8328c2bfb0 : 0xffffff80082d6aa7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008200000
System model name: MacPro3,1 (Mac-F42C88C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 22848684012076
last loaded kext at 21765578187511: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7f8ab6a000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 3628732647188: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7f8ab6a000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.filesystems.prlufs    2010.12.28
com.parallels.kext.vnic 9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.hidhook  9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   9.0 24172.951362
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   9.0 24172.951362
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
rabb.it.driver.RabbitEars   2.1.4
com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport 4.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.18
com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver  3.9.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   360.8.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver 1.1.9
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.1.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX2000    8.1.8
com.apple.kext.AMD4800Controller    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.iPodSBCDriver  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleIntel8254XEthernet    3.1.3b1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   700.36.24
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.3f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.1.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    380
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
Model: MacPro3,1, BootROM MP31.006C.B05, 8 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz, 28 GB, SMC 1.25f4
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4870, ATI Radeon HD 4870, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 1, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 2, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 1, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 2, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344754373255344E443142442D334320
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 3, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0D9B, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 4, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0D9B, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 3, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000463732353642363145353636374600
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 4, 4 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000463732353642363145353636374600
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 22 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Ethernet 2, Ethernet, en1
PCI Card: NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT, Display Controller, Slot-2
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 4870, Display Controller, Slot-1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series, 256.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS723020BLA642, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST3000DM001-9YN166, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST2000DM001-9YN164, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: ST3000DM001-9YN166, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS722020ALA330, 2 TB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Xbox NUI Camera
USB Device: Xbox NUI Audio
USB Device: Xbox NUI Motor
USB Device: iPod
USB Device: Logitech Camera
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: Apple Cinema HD Display
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
FireWire Device: unknown_device, Unknown
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

I ran memtest and it passed all tests, so I don't think it is a memory issue.

```
Rember Test Results

All tests passed!

Total built-in memory: 28 GB


    This is the total amount of physical memory that the computer has installed.  If this figure is not showing the correct amount of memory there may be a problem with one or more installed DIMMS.

Available memory: 22686 MB

    Available memory is the amount of physical memory that is currently not in use by any other processes.  All available memory will be used for testing when the "All" option is selected. To increase the amount of available memory, you can restart your computer before testing. If you are familiar with the command line (CLI), you can run memtest (the core of Rember) in single-user mode. See Rember help, or http://www.memtestosx.org for more information.

Requested amount: All MB

    The total amount of memory requested for testing by the Rember application. Not all requested memory can be allocated for testing. See information on "Available memory" for more information.

Memory allocated for testing: 22686 MB

    This is the total amount of memory that memtest was able to allocate for testing.  See "Available memory" section for more information.

-------

Loops selected: 1

    Total loops selected by user for testing. All loops should complete when testing is successful. Test failure when the "Continue on Error" preference is selected will cancel tests before this number of loops has been completed. Users can also cancel testing before this number is reached.

Loops completed: 1

    Total loops completed by memtest.  Note that the Rember is not always able to identify how many loops ran.  If there are discrepancies between this and the loops selected, the log should be examined to determine exactly how many loops were performed.
-------

Total execution time: All tests passed!  Execution time: 21454  seconds

    This is the total amount of time that it took to execute the selected tests. Execution time may vary from system to system, and is provided as a guide for determining how long users can expect tests to run based on the amount of memory installed on the system.

Testing start time: 2014-01-12 14:31:37 +0000

Testing end time: 2014-01-12 20:29:28 +0000


Rember version: 0.3.7b Memtest version: 4.
```

Comment: One simple bit of maintenance ... open up the case and clear out all the dust.

Comment: I tried that. One recent thing I've noticed is that the panics only happen when my computer goes to sleep. I prevented my computer from sleeping and haven't had a panic, but don't want to constantly draw this much energy all the time. Any ideas what might be causing it to panic during sleep?

Comment: Use Terminal to run the command shown at http://pastebin.com/PjBZgSba then restart the Mac. You'll get verbose boot, verbose shut down and more importantly: the next .panic file will show more information in the backtrace.