# MBP frequent crashes from kernel panic caused by memory faults?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

There are 4 very similar crash reports listed here: http://pastebin.com/y7NUNJt6
The starting lines suggest to me it might be a CRC check failure but what do I know ;-)
This tends to happen with the lid closed and the machine not yet in sleep. Do I have bad/overheating memory? A similar report [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116890/unknown-cause-of-recent-kernel-panics) was not solved.

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801f209f4a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa0dee3d2, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000022e0b000, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1
```

Comment: First trick for any kernel panics is to eliminate non-apple kexts - in this case com.intel.kext.intelhaxm;
com.AmbrosiaSW.AudioSupport; & 
com.protech.NoSleep 1.4.0

Comment: I removed NoSleep first now because I see it happening with lid closing/sleeping. We'll see if that solved the problem for my MPB. Thanks!